# Am I legally obligated to provide access to my open source project?

Tags: licensing

Suppose I have a peice of software that I am developing with a group of friends. Suppose we license our work under a CC license and publish it on the internet.

**My question:**

If we license our software as open source are we legally obligated to provide access to the source code? If no, why not? Is this just optional?

Comment: Related question: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/777/why-are-cc-licenses-not-good-for-software

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creative Commons licenses [aren't appropriate for software](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Can_I_apply_a_Creative_Commons_license_to_software.3F), in particular because they contain no requirement on the availability of source code. So technically (and legally) you could distribute your software as binaries under a CC license, and licensees would be allowed to modify the binaries, but that wouldn't be open source by any definition.

The [Open Source Definition](http://opensource.org/osd), section 2, requires the availability of source code:

> The program must include source code, and must allow distribution in source code as well as compiled form. Where some form of a product is not distributed with source code, there must be a well-publicized means of obtaining the source code for no more than a reasonable reproduction cost preferably, downloading via the Internet without charge. The source code must be the preferred form in which a programmer would modify the program. Deliberately obfuscated source code is not allowed. Intermediate forms such as the output of a preprocessor or translator are not allowed.